# python - iterating through a code and implementing it into shapes on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def draw_pattern(a_canvas, size, pattern_str_list):
    x0 = size
    x1 = x0 + size
    y0 = size
    y1 = y0 + size

    for word in pattern_str_list:
      for char in word:

         if char == "A":
            a_canvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill = "gray")
            x0 = x0 + size
            x1 = x0 + size
         if char == "B":
            a_canvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill = "red")
            x0 = x0 + size
            x1 = x0 + size
         if char == "C":
            a_canvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill = "blue")
            x0 = x0 + size
            x1 = x0 + size
         if char == "D":
            a_canvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill = "green")
            x0 = x0 + size
            x1 = x0 + size
         if char == "_":
            a_canvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill = "black")
            x0 = x0 + size
            x1 = x0 + size


        y0 += size
```

Hi there, I am trying to build a program that takes a list of strings, read and takes the data from it and displays shapes in rows next to each other through the tkinter widget depending on what is in the list. Let's say the `a_canvas` is a large square grid, `size = 50` and `pattern_str_list = (ABC, D_A, BB__A_D)`. How can I iterate through the list and display the correct colored circle and then move onto the row below for the next item in the list?

Basically so it looks like:

gray red blue

green black gray

red red black gray green

in colored circles on tkinter?

Comment: your snippet has done it, what's your question now?

Comment: It doesn't work when I run it though the first and third row appear but the 2nd row is just a line still on the 1st row

Comment: what have you done to debug this? Have you confirmed that `word`, `char`, `size`, `x0`, `y0`, `x1`, and `y1` are what you think they are?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
def draw_pattern(a_canvas, size, pattern_str_list):
    colours = {"A":"gray", "B":"red", "C":"blue", "D":"green"}
    x = size
    y = size

    for word in pattern_str_list:
        for char in word:
            a_canvas.create_oval(x, y , x + size, y + size, fill=colours.get(char, "black"))
            x += size
        y += size
```